# Convert Scala Object to Int or Long dynamically

Tags: scala

I get a value as `Object` from a method. I know that this object will be either of type `Int` or of type `Long`, however I do not know in advance which one it will be. How do I cast it to `Int` or `Long` ?

Unfortunately I can't change the return type of the method providing this, so that will not work as a solution. .

Comment: If it returns `Object`, how can you know it's a number?

Comment: are you converting string to Int/Long? please provide more details what are you planning to achieve.

Comment: No it's not a `String`. They are just regular numbers which are coming in as `Object` data type. And I'm sure that it's always a mathematical number.

Comment: @Abhishek got some more context? Untyped APIs are always a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a real problem in your library API if a method that only returns `Int`s or `Long`s is typed as `Object`. However, you can deal with it.
However, the following pattern matching should work:

```
val five: Object = 5 //your method output

five match {
  case n: java.lang.Integer => doSomethingWithInt(n)
  case n: java.lang.Long => doSomethingWithLong(n)
}
```

You need to use `java.lang` because `Int` and `Long` are actually the primitive types `int` and `long`, so they do not inherit `Object`.

Comment: You might want to add a default pattern to handle the fallback case where the method returns something other than an `int` or a `long` (maybe the implementation changes at some point in the future), e.g. `case _ => throw new Exception(s"Expected int or long, got ${five.getClass.getName} instead")`. While the compiler will add a default handler that throws a generic exception, providing a more-specific exception is always useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `object.asInstanceOf[T]` to cast to the desired type :)

Comment: Yes but the problem here is, I don't know whether `[T]` is `Int` or `Long`. So I get RunTime Error if I try to instantiate `Int` as `Long` or vice-versa.